# understanding Nodejs using requirejs

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I'm reading the documentation of using requirejs in node. But I'm confused by "passing top-level js files require to requirejs".Below is the part of the documentation from require.js:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
    //function to requirejs so that node modules
    //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
    nodeRequire: require
});
```

What does this line of code: "nodeRequire: require" means?
I comment out this line and require runs correctly on node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first line you're using the `require()`-function of node.js.

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
```

This means the "real" function is stored in a variable named "require". You're now passing this function to requirejs.

```
requirejs.config({
    nodeRequire: require
});
```

You're currently in your top-level directory e.g. `/path/myproject`. Now if you require something within `/path/myproject/lib/another.js` it will load modules relative to `/path/myproject` and not to `/path/myproject/lib/another.js`.

Try it out and require a module within a subdirectory with and without `nodeRequire: require`.

Comment: thanks Fabio, I tried require module in subdirectory. it works exactly as you said. btw, if you config the baseUrl and path, requirejs will then follow the baseUrl and path configuration.